# az acr build - who performs the build actually?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

When I run `az acr build` command - where is the actual building happening? What machine? I need IP address of this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided here on Azure ACR GitHub https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/627#issuecomment-1164823149

Answer (score 0):

`az acr build` is a shortcut to an ACR Task. The location of the build machine is not documented (I haven't found anything related) and you don't have access to it.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-overview)